# Selecting x samples randomly with replacement using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, random

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    revisionId  itemId wikidataType
1    307190482      23           Q5
6    305019084      80           Q5
8    303692414     181           Q5
9    306600439     192           Q5
11   294597048     206           Q5
```

In the complete dataframe, there are 100 such different values present in column `wikidataType`. It's a large dataframe, so I want to restrict it to 1000 records per `wikidataType` and I selected it randomly using following:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1000)
        if len(x) > 1000 else x.sample(1000, replace=True))
```

If some types do not have 1000 records then I want to use "with replacement" strategy to have the same number of records for all `wikidataTypes`. Hence, I used `replace=True`. E.g. if for `wikidataType` `Q5` I have 900 records, then I want to repeat some random 100 records but from those 900 records. So finally I will have 900 distinct records, with 100 of them repeating. I used `x.sample(1000, replace=True)` but that gave me only 4 distinct records for type `Q5`, each of them was repeated many times, when I actually had 1000 distinct records for that type. How can I resolve this?